# Facebook advertising through SDK?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps, facebook-social-plugins, facebook-sdk-3.0

I would like to explore the facebook SDK, specifically posting advertisements.

Browsed for few hours but didnt get proper answer for my question.

Any answer on the feasibility and the code snippet would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "posting advertisements"? Creating Ads on Facebook via the API? Your question seems to be very broad, I would suggest asking about a specific problem you have and not just "I want to use the Facebook SDK, how do I do it?"

Comment: Yes creating ads on facebook via the API, you got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Ads API of Facebook is currently only available to whitelisted apps [1]. You have to apply to to get access to it. However the documentation [2] of the Ads API is public, in case you just want to have a look at how it works.

[1] https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/overview/
[2] https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ads-api